Where to locate idea.properties for Android Studio in mac?
I am creating a patch and it exceeds the memory limit.
I am getting the below error

Error creating patch: Cannot show the contents of '/Users/wishygupta/Desktop/src/main/res/raw/video.mp4'. The file is bigger than 20.97 MB.  You can override this restriction by increasing the idea.max.vcs.loaded.size.kb property in the 'idea.properties' file.
Where can I find 'idea.properties' file on Mac.

I've found it here: /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties
